# Simulink Raspberry Hardware External Mode Error Issue

Tags: matlab, raspberry-pi, monitoring, external, simulink

I have a problem using Raspbery Pi hardware and Simulink, shown by the pictures below.

I'm tring to control an LED and GPIO pin on the Raspberry Pi.

- I click Build, Deploy & Start. It works.
- But then I click Monitor & Tune for monitoring signals.

It produces an error which I cannot find a solution for.

I tried different versions of Matlab but got the same error.

My hardware settings are just like in this link: https://www.mathworks.com/help/supportpkg/raspberrypi/examples/communicating-with-raspberry-pi-hardware.html

In addition I tried to click connect on external mode panel and the result is the same, the error is same.

Do you have any suggestions?

[Cross posted from [Matlab Answers](https://www.mathworks.com/matlabcentral/answers/508340-simulink-raspberry-hardware-external-mode-error-issue)].

[image: Pic 1]
[image: pic 2]

Answer (score 0):

Check your matlab search path. You have the support package 2019a and 2019b on your search path. Add only the one matching your matlab version.